# Why does EF load data from the database and ignores local changes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
        var existingParticipant = Context.CaseParticipants.Where(p => p.CaseId == caseId);
        foreach (var cp in existingParticipant)
        {
            var ncp = caseParticipantList.First(a => a.Id == cp.Id);
            cp.IsIncompetent = ncp.IsIncompetent;
            cp.IsLeave = ncp.IsLeave;
            cp.SubstituteUserId = ncp.IsPresent ? null : ncp.SubstituteUserId;
        }
        var withSubs = existingParticipant.Where(c => c.SubstituteUserId != null).ToList();
```

What surprised me is that the last line fetches the rows from the DB a second time, ignoring any changes I've just done in the previous lines, why is that, and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that your `existingParticipant` is a query and not a list. That query gets executed for the `foreach`, but `existingParticipant` still stays a query that will get executed on the database when calling `ToList()` again. To solve it execute the initial query straight away and that way you work in memory on your changed entities.

```
IList<...> existingParticipant = Context.CaseParticipants.Where(p => p.CaseId == caseId).ToList(); // Explicit executing of query
foreach (var cp in existingParticipant)
{
    var ncp = caseParticipantList.First(a => a.Id == cp.Id);
    cp.IsIncompetent = ncp.IsIncompetent;
    cp.IsLeave = ncp.IsLeave;
    cp.SubstituteUserId = ncp.IsPresent ? null : ncp.SubstituteUserId;
}
var withSubs = existingParticipant.Where(c => c.SubstituteUserId != null).ToList(); // Working in memory on list
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of existingParticipants is IQueryable, that means you won't get the objects into memory but only a query itself working on database directly

If you want to process your objects into memory call .ToList() after

Context.CaseParticipants.Where(p => p.CaseId == caseId)